# how does countimedown timer work likewise three times?

Tags: java, c#, android

i have code block as below shown. for examaple Can i work this code three times?

when i used for loop or other loops. it isnt performed i wanted process.

```
new CountDownTimer(3000,1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {


                    gostertext.setText(""+l/1000);
                    durumgoster.setText("KOŞ..");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    gostertext.setText("KOŞU bitti YÜRÜ");
                    CountDownTimer counter=new CountDownTimer(3000,1000) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long l) {
                            gostertext.setText(""+l/1000);
                            durumgoster.setText("YÜRÜ..");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            gostertext.setText("bitti");
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            }.start();
```

when a counter ended, other counter will start that will perform three times.
i writed code as over shown that is worked but i want to perform three times.
Can we solve this problem?

Comment: Please don't tag spam.

Answer (score 0):

why not make the loops contents into 1 void,
and call it three times?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like(untested):

```
int countCounter = 0;
CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer() {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        if (countCounter < 3){
            countCounter++;
            // cancel the counter and restart it!
            mCountDownTimer.cancel();
            mCountDownTimer.start();
        }
    }
};
```